# How can a war not unpack although unpackWar is set to true?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

this is puzzling me : although unpackWARs is set to 'true' in /etc/tomcat7/server.xml, and unpackWAR cannot be found anywhere else (including context.xml), the WAR keeps remaining packed. It does never unpack!

```
   <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

The VM is a clone from another one where the war unpacks as soon as tomcat starts. Thus, the configuration should be exactly the same... and I cannot understand why it acts differently there!

Is there another place (but for server.xml and context.xml) that states whether the wars should unpack or not? 
Any hint on where I should look, or how I can ensure the war is unpacked?

Thanks for your reading and help!

Comment: what does it say in Catalina.out? Is there any error occurring before it deploys the war? If everything loads correctly some lines about deployment time should be the last entries in Catalina.out if you clear your logs then restart Tomcat with the WAR in the webapps folder.

Comment: Usman, srry for the late answer. I saw nothing specific in catalina.out (nothing that would point more or less obvious pb regarding, let's say, permission problem)

Answer (score 1):

ensure the config syntax worked probably by run the script under:
"tomcat-home"/bin/configtest.sh

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This didn't point out any obvious problem, but at least, I learned something!

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for the `unpackWAR` attribute in `Context` from http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html:

> If false, the unpackWARs attribute of the owning Host will be overridden and the WAR file will not be unpacked. If true, the value of the owning Host's unpackWARs attribute will determine if the WAR is unpacked. If not specified, the default value is true.

Check the context's configuration - make extra *extra* sure that you didn't look for `unpackWARs`, because the context attribute name is singular, `unpackWAR`.

Also, context.xml might be packaged in the WAR file, or be in `conf/localhost` (or whatever you configure as hostname in `conf/`)

**In addition** check permissions&ownership on the webapps folder (and temp), where you'd expect the WAR file to unzip. I'd expect this to show up in the logs, but one never knows (they might be write protected as well...). A common problem that I'm seeing is: Someone "accidentally" starts tomcat as root, which changes a lot of file&directory ownerships, ruining it for later when run with the proper unprivileged user account.

The tomcat user on one of the machine might have a different user id than on the other - which might lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Olaf, thanks for the help. Though, we checked many times for extra (and undesired!) 's', and found none. Also, we looked for any 'context.xml' file, and also in app' war, but none of them hold that parameter... Thus, I am still puzzled about this :)

Answer (score 1):

Little late, but it might help. I checked server configuration.
Double click here if you use eclipse.

[image]

And you will find "Deploy path" as below. If it is not webapps, you should change it to webapps if your configuration is set as webapps. (server.xml)
I think it is default setting so you might want to check.

[image]

Comment: Kim, I quit working on this project a year ago, and I don't know if they still have the problem (and don't have the required access to check). Though, thanks for adding your tip : this may help someone who encounters the same pb.