# tomcat8 war not unpacking on redeploy

Tags: tomcat8

I run powershell script to delete a war file in tomcat8 webapps, then copy a new war to the webapp directory.
(Not allowed to deploy maven on customers production server).
The war file does not unpack.
I have unpackWARs="true" in tomcats server.xml (although this should be default)´
This has worked before.
Also have same problem after upgrading to tomcat9.
I use maven to build the application.

Comment: did you add `autoDeploy="true"`?

Comment: Yes it is in the config

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a war not unpack although unpackWar is set to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372336/how-can-a-war-not-unpack-although-unpackwar-is-set-to-true)